# Use of CoGetClassObject() in C - access COM Object interface

Tags: c++, c, windows, com

Instruction on accessing a interface to an application, in **plain** C/C++ **without**:

- MFC
- ATL
- WTL

Basically, I would like to make use of a COM object.

Working sample source code or guidance - to **using** (functionality) a COM object, **not** creating a COM server.

Regards

Comment: I'd really suggest you look at ATL. (WTL won't help; MFC is bloated) The 3 helper classes CComPtr, CComBSTR, CComVariant will make your life infinitely easier, & for using other COM objects you don't need much more than that.

Comment: Hi, I'd consider ATL - for simplicity, but I'd rather/like to learn/handle all control manually. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example in plain C++:

```
CoInitialize(NULL); // absolutely essential: initialize the COM subsystem
IMyInterface* pIFace;
// create the object and obtain a pointer to the sought interface
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyObject, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMyInterface, &pIFace);
pIFace->MethodIReallyNeed(); // use the object
pIFace->Release(); // free the object
CoUninitialize(); // cleanup COM after you're done using its services
```

Copied from here: [COM Basics](http://netez.com/2xExplorer/shellFAQ/bg_com.html)

Answer (score 3):

There's an article on CodeProject, [Introduction to COM - What It Is and How to Use It](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/comintro.aspx) that you may find useful. It gives a pretty good introduction and a worked example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming you have the interface declaration, all you need is a call to CoInitialize in order to initialize COM, then CoCreateInstance to get your instance (and use it), and then optionally, CoUnInitialize to uninitialize COM.

Comment: CasperOne, do you have a small example? I'm not familiar to Windows programming - I'm from Linux world...

Answer (score 0):

Avoid codeproject (newbie), and see all MSDN chapters about COM.

Everything is there, with tons of C and C++ sample codes

Answer (score 0):

Just refer a good book on COM (Don Box or Dale Rougerson). Those are the good starting points to COM World.